# JavaFX - draw line with arrow (Canvas)

Tags: canvas, javafx

I have problem with rewrite this code to JavaFX:

```
private final int ARR_SIZE = 8;

void drawArrow(Graphics g1, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) g1.create();
    g.setPaint(Color.BLACK);

    double dx = x2 - x1, dy = y2 - y1;
    double angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
    int len = (int) Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(x1, y1);
    at.concatenate(AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(angle));
    g.transform(at);

    g.drawLine(0, 0, len, 0);
    g.fillPolygon(new int[] { len, len - ARR_SIZE, len - ARR_SIZE, len }, new int[] { 0, -ARR_SIZE, ARR_SIZE, 0 },
            4);
}
```

my solution is not working correctly because the result of code:

```
drawArrow(gc, 200, 50, 50, 50);
```

is

[image: arrow].

Expected result is

[image: arrow2].

```
private final int ARR_SIZE = 8;

void drawArrow(GraphicsContext gc, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {

    gc.setFill(Color.BLACK);

    double dx = x2 - x1, dy = y2 - y1;
    double angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
    int len = (int) Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

    Affine affine = new Affine(Affine.translate(x1, y1));
    affine.createConcatenation(Affine.rotate(angle, 0, 0));
    gc.setTransform(affine);

    gc.strokeLine(0, 0, len, 0);
    gc.fillPolygon(new double[]{len, len - ARR_SIZE, len - ARR_SIZE, len}, new double[]{0, -ARR_SIZE, ARR_SIZE, 0},
            4);

}
```

can you help me pls ?

Comment: You would have to explain yourself better. What's not working? What is wrong with the result you are getting? What do you expect to achieve?

Comment: Hi, expected result is **<------------**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 reasons for this:

1. Rotating by radians instead of degrees: `Transform.rotate` expects the angle in degrees (see [javadoc for `Rotate` constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/transform/Rotate.html#Rotate-double-double-double-); javadoc for `Transform.rotate` "redirects" there), but [`Math.atan2`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#atan2-double-double-) returns radians.
2. [`Transform.createConcatenation`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/transform/Transform.html#createConcatenation-javafx.scene.transform.Transform-) creates a new `Transform` instead of modifying the existing `Transform`.

This code should work:

```
void drawArrow(GraphicsContext gc, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
    gc.setFill(Color.BLACK);

    double dx = x2 - x1, dy = y2 - y1;
    double angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
    int len = (int) Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

    Transform transform = Transform.translate(x1, y1);
    transform = transform.createConcatenation(Transform.rotate(Math.toDegrees(angle), 0, 0));
    gc.setTransform(new Affine(transform));

    gc.strokeLine(0, 0, len, 0);
    gc.fillPolygon(new double[]{len, len - ARR_SIZE, len - ARR_SIZE, len}, new double[]{0, -ARR_SIZE, ARR_SIZE, 0},
            4);
}
```