# Arrow from Line JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, pane

How can I make arrow from line? I need to build directed and undirected graph, so I can draw edge, but can't draw arrow. I have this Edge code and I want to make an arrow from it. I hope you help me)

```
public class Edge extends Group {

protected Cell source;
protected Cell target;

Line line;

public Edge(Cell source, Cell target) {

    this.source = source;
    this.target = target;

    source.addCellChild(target);
    target.addCellParent(source);

    line = new Line();

    line.startXProperty().bind(source.layoutXProperty().add(source.getBoundsInParent().getWidth() / 2.0));
    line.startYProperty().bind(source.layoutYProperty().add(source.getBoundsInParent().getHeight() / 2.0));

    line.endXProperty().bind(target.layoutXProperty().add( target.getBoundsInParent().getWidth() / 2.0));
    line.endYProperty().bind(target.layoutYProperty().add( target.getBoundsInParent().getHeight() / 2.0));

   getChildren().addAll(line);
}

public Cell getSource() {
    return source;
}

public Cell getTarget() {
    return target;
}

public void setColor (Paint color){
    line.setStroke(color);
}

public void setWidth(double width){
    line.setStrokeWidth(width);
}
```

}

Comment: [Like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027613/how-to-draw-a-directed-arrow-line-in-java)?

Comment: [Or this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35751576/javafx-draw-line-with-arrow-canvas)?